# What inspired the use of the term "gauge" in gauge theories?

Tags: physics, particle-physics

Gauge theories in physics are theories that introduce extra fields, the mediating fields, after the non-mediated fields are gauged.

Now to gauge something means that you set some reference point from which measurements are made. But what is set in non-interacting fields? Why were the (arbitrary or non-arbitrary) phase transformations on matter/energy fields seen as gauges? Who came up with that idea?

Comment: People say Weyl, but the idea goes back. Weyl called scale invariance of his theory Eichinvarianz (scale adjustment invariance) inspired by train gauges. Jackson, J. D., & Okun, L. B. (2001). *Historical roots of gauge invariance*. Reviews of Modern Physics, **73** (3), 663.

Comment: I misspoke a little. English has "gauge" for the interval scale of train tracks, but the German Eichung is calibration of scale for just about everything...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I still see no connection with, say, the gauging of my scale in the bathroom. Are the matter fields the scale, so to speak? From which the interaction fields emerge when you gauge them (locally, that is local gauge transformations; if I gauge my scale though I am always setting it to zero)? Oops. I didnt see your next comment yet.  Its a bit confusing. Scaling the scale...

Comment: But this is a physics question. Weyl scaled the metric (so the standard length) differently in each location, with a local scale transformation. He then proposed to complexity the exponent to accommodate electromagnetism, which has phase gauge invariance, to QM, and associated it to the vector potential, which was ultimately generalized to all gauge fields. The article cited expounds.

Comment: CosmasZachos Yes its a physics question. But I cant ask on that site anymore. But it is a question about how or why it was called that way and by who. I understand the procedures used but I wondered why a phase transformation was called a gauge transformarion.

Comment: The review article details how Weyl was inspired by local scale readjustments at every point in spacetime expressed as a real exponential,  to identify phase transformations in EM now expressed as phases, but also varying with spacetime, as the "same thing"....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Alright! So it is the similar form? One with real exponential (spacetime scalings, the distance between the rail intervals so to speak) and the complex exponential "scalings" of the matter fields. I get it. Im gonna buy your book! Paperback though...

Comment: @CosmasZachos My last question. Really. Can you tell me what the picture on the cover of your book entails? I tried to tell my girlfriend but I cant really...

Comment: It's the Wigner function (phase-space profile) of two separated Gaussian wavepackets, which, in phase space, interfere with each other...

Comment: Actually, [gauge blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_block) are calibration standards in English as well. Gauge is used in firearm calibers as well. It need not be associated with railroad tracks.

Comment: You can create 1000 different (!) lengths between 2 and 3 mm. With 30 blocks. Im typing on a phone. Once and a while my thumb misdirects.